# How to prove that F is constant in this question?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

"Be $f: R^2 \rightarrow  R $ a continuous function that has continuous first order partial derivatives and satisfies the relation $2f_x(x,y)+f_y(x,y) =0$, for all (x, y). Being $f_x$ the derivative with respect to X and $f_y$ the derivative in relation to y, prove that F is constant on the lines of equation x - 2y = c"

Is this question missing information? I don't know how to start.

I know that there is a relation between x and y on the line of equation x - 2y = c, but I don't know how to calculate the integral of F starting of this point to prove that F is constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute for $x$ in the differential equation to get $$2\partial f_x(c+2y,y)+\partial f_y(c+2y,y)=0.$$ Then it follows that $\partial f_x(c+2y,y)=0.$ Consequently, we also have that the second summand vanishes. Since the gradient vanishes, it follows by MVT that the function is constant provided the restraint $x-2y=c$ holds.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, we know $f_y = -2f_x$ everywhere, so if we take a directional derivative, which is the same as taking the dot product of the gradient and the direction (in this case, along the lines), we get zero for the direction specified by the lines. That is, the lines give the direction (2,1), while the gradient is proportional to (1,-2), so the dot product is 2-2=0.